# Parse Json file and save specific values

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON file where the amount of id's sometimes changes (more id's will be added):

```
{
    "maps": [
        {
            "id": "blabla1",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "blabla2",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "blabla3",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "blabla4",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this python code that has to print all the values of ids:

```
import json

data = json.load(open('data.json'))
variable1 = data["maps"][0]["id"]
print(variable1)
variable2 = data["maps"][1]["id"]
print(variable2)
variable3 = data["maps"][2]["id"]
print(variable3)
variable4 = data["maps"][3]["id"]
print(variable4)
```

I have to use variables, because i want to show the values in a dropdown menu. Is it possible to save the values of the id's in a more efficient way? How do you know the max amount of id's of this json file (in de example 4)?

Comment: You can have the values of the ID in a tuple or a list?

Comment: Don't store them in variables, store them in a list. A list knows its length also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data['maps']` is a simple list, so you can iterate over it as such:

```
for map in data['maps']:
    print(map['id'])
```

To store them in a variable, you'll need to output them to a list.  Storing them each in a separate variable is not a good idea, because like you said, you don't have a way to know how many there are.

```
ids = []
for map in data['maps']:
    ids.append(map['id'])
```

Comment: The OP also asked how many IDs were in the list.

Comment: Because of the dropdown menu I want to make, I have to store them in variables. Here I'm stuck. This example is a good way to start

Comment: How are you creating the "dropdown"?  I can't help more without seeing your code for that, or at least what framework.  Please update your question.

Comment: I used a list for the dropdown. Thank you for changing the post with a list! OptionMenu(root, self.dropBoard, *ids).grid(row=0, column=0)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of `id` (which is the number of elements) by checking the `length` of `data['maps']`:

```
number_of_ids = len(data['maps'])
```

A clean way to get all the `id` values is storing them in a `list`.

You can achieve this in a pythonic way like this:

```
list_of_ids = [map['id'] for map in data['maps']]
```

Using this approach you don't even need to store the number of elements in the original `json`, because you iterate through all of them using a `foreach` approach, essentially.

If the pythonic approach troubles you, you can achieve the same thing with a classic `foreach` approach doing so:

```
list_of_ids = []
for map in data['maps']:
    list_of_ids.append(map['id'])
```

Or you can do with a **classic** `for loop`, and here is where you really need the length:

```
number_of_ids = len(data['maps'])
list_of_ids = []
for i in range(0,number_of_ids):
    list_of_ids.append(data['maps'][i]['id'])
```

This last is the classic way, but I suggest you to take the others approaches in order to leverage the advantages python offers to you!

You can find more on this stuff [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)!

Happy coding!

Comment: The poster is having trouble with the concept of a `for` loop.  For now, suggesting list comprehensions to them is too much, in my opinion.

Comment: Mh, allright, I'm going to add the common way too!